# Date formatting not working in Java

Tags: java, date

I need to check the validity of date against a specified format. After googling, I found one:

```
public static boolean isThisDateValid(String dateToValidate, String dateFromat){

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFromat);
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);  
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateToValidate,position);
        return date != null && position.getIndex() == dateFromat.length();

}
```

but it is not working..When I ran this, it returned true instead of false.Month value specified is invalid i.e. 13

```
System.out.println(isThisDateValid("20101331","yyyymmdd"));
```

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 8):

```
yyyymmdd
```

should be

```
yyyyMMdd
```

note `MM` for **Month**
and `mm` is for **Minutes**

Answer (score 7):

Use capital `M` for months:

```
System.out.println(isThisDateValid("20101331","yyyyMMdd"));
```

This invalid test date will return `false` as expected as you've called `setLenient(false)`

[Date Format doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should use "yyyyMMdd" instead of "yyyymmdd"

Explanation is provided [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#month).

Also why in your question, month value is assigned to 13?